# See all users who have a specific file checked out

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, source-control-explorer

When I am in Source Control explorer for Visual Studio 2013, there is a "User" column which will show which users have a specific file checked out. This works fine if one user has the file checked out. However, if multiple users have the file checked out then the User column for the file will read as "Lastname, FirstName, [more]". How do I see who the [more] are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I know of:

1. Use the commandline tool `tf vc status` instead of the UI.
2. Open the properties window of the file in question from the Source Control explorer.[image]

Remember that the checkout status is only reliable when all your team members are using Server Workspaces. On a Local workspace it is not possible to check files out exclusively.